# I got this error while installing react app

Tags: reactjs, failed-installation

I got this error while installing the react app. Perviously, it was working well but, now it started to show this error. How to fix it?

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:614
  throw e;
  ^

Error: No valid exports main found for 'D:\Programming\react\stores\node_modules\is-promise'
    at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:611:9)
    at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:492:14)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:541:12)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:22)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:847:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:69:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\react\stores\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1121:30) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Aborting installation.
  node  has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this issue is related to is-promise issue
https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/14#issue-606798951
they are working for fixing the bug.

Comment: I tried these commands and worked for me.                                                                     
npm rm -g create-react-app
and then install :
npm install -g create-react-app
then create project :
npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: Please include context with a link.